# Java LibGDX box2D applyLinearImpulse() doesn't apply horizontal impulse

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I've recently started using libGDX and box2D, and I've created a platformer that uses applyLinearImpulse to jump vertically and it works well. However, when I try to apply an impulse in the x direction to create a dash, it doesn't work.

This code works as intended:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE) && jumpCounter < 2) {
            float force = body.getMass() * 18;
            body.setLinearVelocity(body.getLinearVelocity().x,0);
            body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, force), body.getPosition(), true);
            jumpCounter ++;
        }
```

But when I try to apply it in the same way in the x direction it does not work.

```
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.K)) {
            float force = body.getMass() * 18;
             body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(force, 0), body.getPosition(), true);
            
        }
```

This is all I've done to set up my world, so I'm not sure if there is another method needed.

```
this.world = new World(new Vector2(0,-25f), false);
```

And this is how the body is created.

```
public static Body createBody(float x, float y, float width, float height, boolean isStatic, World world) {
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = isStatic ? BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody : BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(x/32.0f, y/32.0f);
    bodyDef.fixedRotation = false;
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(width/2/32.0f, height/2/32.0f);
    
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.density = 0.2f;
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.friction=0;
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    shape.dispose();
    return body;
```

What would need to be changed for this impulse to work?